# Cannot Access my Files on External APFS SSD in "Other Volumes"

Tags: macos, ssd, external-disk, storage, apfs

On my external SSD, which is formatted as APFS (Case-sensitive), there are a lot of important personal files (around 219 GB).

When I plug the drive into my MacBook Pro (M1 Pro, 2021) and open it in finder, the folder is empty. However, when I take a look at it in disk utility, I can see that in fact, the drive is 85 % full, but all my files are in "Other Volumes".

How can I recover my files from "Other Volumes"? I could not find anything related to this in multiple hours of Google-ing. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Edit: Here is a screenshot of Disk Utility with "Show All Devices" enabled in the view menu:

[image]

The output from `diskutil list` is as follows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         494.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +494.4 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            9.1 GB     disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.1 GB     disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 9.2 GB     disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                794.7 MB   disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    454.2 GB   disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk3s6

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         255.9 GB   disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +255.9 GB   disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume ValentinSSD             737.3 KB   disk5s2
```

The "Sabrent" external drive was a different external drive connected to my Mac. It has nothing to do with the ValentinSSD drive. For this edit, I removed the "Sabrent" drive from my Mac.

Comment: Is this just an external drive formatted APFS or did this come from another Mac as a system/data volume?

Comment: It is just an external drive formatted as APFS. It contains files such as pictures and documents.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I’m trying to replicate the conditions to see how to solve.

Comment: Can you replace your Disk Utility screenshot with one where you have enabled Show All Devices in the View menu. As it stands the Other Volumes could be the Sabrent volume.  The output of the Terminal command `diskutil list` would also be useful.

Comment: I edited the question and added the new screenshot as well as the terminal output. The Sabrent drive is a different external drive that has nothing to do with the problematic drive.

Comment: Thanks that is much clearer. `diskutil` all looks good. I have no idea why Disk Utility is showing Other Volumes. Have you run 'First Aid' on both the container disk 5 and the ValantinSSD volume?

Comment: I have now run First Aid on both, but now „Other Volume“ is gone, and with it all of my data

Comment: Can you recommend a tool that lets me recover my data?

Comment: That's bad, but there wasn't much else you could have done.  1) Recover from your backup. 2) An app like Disk Drill. 3) Professional recovery service.